# Sonarr/Radarr Remote path mapping to docker transmission

Tags: docker, torrent, transmission, plex

I'm trying to setup a Sonarr/Radarr server for my plex and I therefor need a torrenter. Currently I use Transmission but I'm not able to get the data from it. Everything works fine until the point where the system shall get the file.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Request Failed: value [/downloads/complete/Angry Birds (2016) [YTS.AG]]  is not a valid Windows path. paths must be a full path eg. C:\Windows
Parameternamn: path

System.ArgumentException: value [/downloads/complete/Angry Birds (2016) [YTS.AG]]  is not a valid Windows path. paths must be a full path eg. C:\Windows
Parameternamn: path
   vid NzbDrone.Common.EnsureThat.EnsureStringExtensions.IsValidPath(Param`1 param) i C:\projects\radarr-usby1\src\NzbDrone.Common\EnsureThat\EnsureStringExtensions.cs:rad 109
   vid NzbDrone.Common.Disk.DiskProviderBase.FolderExists(String path) i C:\projects\radarr-usby1\src\NzbDrone.Common\Disk\DiskProviderBase.cs:rad 83
   vid NzbDrone.Core.MediaFiles.MovieImport.Manual.ManualImportService.GetMediaFiles(String path, String downloadId) i C:\projects\radarr-usby1\src\NzbDrone.Core\MediaFiles\MovieImport\Manual\ManualImportService.cs:rad 83
   vid NzbDrone.Api.ManualImport.ManualImportModule.GetMediaFiles() i C:\projects\radarr-usby1\src\NzbDrone.Api\ManualImport\ManualImportModule.cs:rad 26
   vid NzbDrone.Api.REST.RestModule`1.<set_GetResourceAll>b__32_0(Object options) i C:\projects\radarr-usby1\src\NzbDrone.Api\REST\RestModule.cs:rad 111
   vid CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Func`2 , Object )
   vid Nancy.Routing.Route.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3(Object parameters, CancellationToken context)
```

The directory where the files are stored is in: `D:\MovieFiles\Downloads\complete`. But I cant access it and I therefor tried remote path mapping but it gives the error above. From the torrent client that runs on a vm is placed in `/host_mnt/d/MovieFiles/Downloads`.

```
Host: 192.168.1.228
Remote path: /host_mnt/d/MovieFiles/Downloads/complete
Local Path: D:\MovieFiles\Downloads\
```

Any clues how I could connect them together? Starting to give up after I been trying to fix this for 3 days without any success.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with the path mapping feature as you have tried. Please try remove the `\` from your windows path so that it looks like `D:\MovieFiles\Downloads`. You might also want to review the Sonarr FAQ which has some info on this [here](https://github.com/Sonarr/Sonarr/wiki/Completed-Download-Handling#all-download-client-on-different-computer).

Also for this to work, the `host` address must match in Sonarr's settings for **Remote Path Mappings** and **Download Clients**. Another person had a similar issue [here](https://forums.sonarr.tv/t/sab-remote-mappings-3-machines-linux-windows/11002/5).

Comment: Explain why this is an answer to the question.

Comment: @JeroenHeier, the pathname might not be valid when the \ on the end.

Comment: See https://github.com/Sonarr/Sonarr/wiki/Completed-Download-Handling#all-download-client-on-different-computer

The download client sends a path to the file (such as D:\Downloads) but sonarr doesn't know what that path mean (not aware of that file system). To solve it we need a map to translate D:\Downloads to a folder that is accessible by the container such as /download). This is why the above remote mapping is needed.